# Are there any agent based cognitive models that are inspired by complex systems studies of ant colonies and economies?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, computational-modeling, economics

I think that certain aspects of ant colony behavior seem almost like economic decision-making in behavior. There are also links between ant colony optimization and features of the brain like selective attention. I was just wondering if any research group has taken up the problems of cognition from the perspectives of economics and/or ant colonies.

It may seem to be mostly analogy on the surface, but the interface of the three seems like a fruitful area to look for new ideas.

Comment: Agreed! A very interesting prospect. Welcome to cogsci.SE.

Answer (score 4):

### Partial answer:

Douglas Hofstadter has written quite a lot about this from a more philosophical approach.
His style isn't for everyone, I think it's introduced well in [this chapter ('Ant Fugue')](http://people.whitman.edu/%7Eherbrawt/classes/110/hofstadter.PDF).

For more applied work from the same, you might look at Mitchell and Hofstadter's CopyCat model of analogies (described briefly [here](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Emm/amcas.pdf), as well as on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copycat_(software))).

All this aside, I don't know of any empirical work along the same lines, but I wouldn't rule it out.

Comment: Thanks for the paper. I think Mitchell is a good place to start. I don't know what to make of Hofstadter's chapter as yet, I'll have to see what I can glean from it.